# If left inverse exists, what does it imply about right inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A, B$ are $n \times m$ complex matrices ($n > m$) with the following property:
\begin{equation}
B^\dagger A = I
\end{equation}
where $I$ is a $m \times m$ identity matrix.

What do we know about $A B^\dagger$?

I know it cannot be the $n \times n$ identity matrix. My intuition is that $A B^\dagger$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with zeros on the off-diagonals, zeros on the $n - m$ main diagonal entries, and $1$ on the $m$ main diagonal entries. If this is true how would one go about proving this? If this is not true is there something we can say in general about this product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to replace $B^{\dagger}$ by $B$.

If $BA = I$ then we have $(AB)^2 = A(BA)B = AB$ so $AB$ is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence); in particular it has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ and is diagonalizable.  We also have the general result that $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same characteristic polynomial ignoring factors of $t$, from which it follows that the multiplicity of $1$ as an eigenvalue is $m$. (Alternatively, we can just observe that $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA) = m$, but the above argument continues to work in positive characteristic.)

So $AB$ it is similar to a matrix of the form you describe but need not be a matrix of the form you describe on the nose. In fact $AB$ can be any idempotent matrix of rank $m$.

To see this, geometrically the condition $BA = I$ says that $A$ is an injective linear map $V \to W$ and $B$ is a surjective linear map $W \to V$ which projects back down to $V$; this implies that if we take $U = \text{ker}(B)$ then $W$ decomposes as a direct sum $V \oplus U$, and in terms of this direct sum $A$ is the inclusion of the first summand and $B$ is the projection to the first summand. So $AB$ is the map $(v, u) \to (v, 0)$ which projects from $W$ down to $V$ but regarded as a subspace of $W$. Every idempotent linear map $P$ arises in this way for a unique choice of $V$, $U$, namely $P = \text{im}(P), U = \text{ker}(P)$.

Answer (score 3):

We know a few things, but not much. In particular, your intuition is false as stated. For example,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
0 & 2 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
but
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
0 & 2 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
Even this block diagonal form came from me being a little lazy with the counterexample.

There's always some slack when choosing left inverses of rectangular matrices. If we consider them as linear maps, having $BA = I$ implies $A$ is an injective linear map (in matrix terms, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent). In fact, this property is equivalent to admitting a left-inverse.

If our matrix is not square, say $n \times m$ for $m < n$, then the linear map is injective, but not surjective. On the image of this map (in matrix terms, the columnspace), which is an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{C}^n$, there is a unique inverse map back to $\Bbb{C}^m$. To get a left inverse, a map from $\Bbb{C}^n$ to $\Bbb{C}^m$, we get to **freely** extend this unique inverse on the image of the map to the entirety of $\Bbb{C}^n$. This gives us freedom of choice, which we can use to mess up your intuition.